# How to correctly define one-to-many relations with existing joint table using node Sequelize

Tags: mysql, sql, node.js, sequelize.js

I am using [Sequelize](http://sequelizejs.com/documentation), but since I also have other servers running other than node.js, I need to let them share the database. So when defining one-to-many relation, I need to let Sequelize use the old existing jointTable.

I write my definition of the association as below, where `pid` is the primary key of `presentations`:

```
this.courses.hasMany(this.presentations,
                     {as             : 'Presentations',
                      foreignKey     : 'cid',
                      joinTableName : 'course_presentations'
});
```

Or this one:

```
this.courses.hasMany(this.presentations,
                     {as             : 'Presentations',
                      foreignKey     : 'pid',
                      joinTableName : 'course_presentations'
});
```

I am using the below codes to retrieve the associated presentations:

```
app.get('/courses/presentations/:cid', function (req, res){
     var cid = req.params.cid;
     app.models.courses.find({where: {cid:cid}}).success(function(course){
         course.getPresentations().success(function(presentations){
             res.send(presentations);
         });
     });
 });
```

The previous one will tell me `there is no cid in 'presentations' table`.

The latter one will give something like this:

```
Executing: SELECT * FROM `courses`;
Executing: SELECT * FROM `courses` WHERE `courses`.`cid`='11' LIMIT 1;
Executing: SELECT * FROM `presentations` WHERE `presentations`.`pid`=11;
```

Check carefully, I found that everytime, it is always using the `cid` value to query for `presentations`, which means only when they happen to share the same id value, something can be returned. And even for those, it is not correct.

I am strongly suspecting, Sequelize are not using the joinTable I specified, instead, it is still trying to find the foreign keys in the original two tables. It is viewing `pid` as the reference of `cid` in presentations, which causes this problem.

So I am wondering how to correctly set up the junction table so that the two of them can use the foreign keys correctly.

Comment: Here they are talking about the many-to-many jointables have flaws, is that true? https://github.com/sequelize/sequelize/issues/745

Answer (score 0):

```
jointTableName : 'course_presentations'
```

should be (without a t)

```
joinTableName : 'course_presentations'
```

Comment: Sorry for the typo, but actually I defined three join relations, only this one has this typo. And after I changed that, the problem still exists.

Answer (score 0):

Actually AFAIK - this kind of relation is not "pure" one-to-many.

You have one course can have many entries in course_presenation table, and course_presentation have one-to-one relation with presentation. If so, just define that kind of associations in model.